# Как сделать словарь к которому можно обращаться через точку

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Необходимо написать словарь к которому можно обращаться как к словарю aiogram'a.

Пример, есть словарь `genMessage` - это самый обычный словарь:

```
genMessage = {
        'from_user': {
            'id': userId,
            'username': username,
            'full_name': fullName
        }
    }
```

И к этому словарю можно обращаться только так:

```
genMessage['from_user']['id']
```

А мне необходимо обращаться к словарю через точку, как к aiogram словарю, пример:

```
genMessage.from_user.id
```

Comment: никак, потому что это будет не словарь

Comment: А в чем необходимость?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Энтерпрайзный" вариант: описываем "схему" словаря/json, т.е. все объекты, которые встречаются внутри словаря, и отношения между ними, потом парсим словарь в эти объекты, и потом уже обращаемся к полям этих объектов через точку.

Один из плюсов такого варианта - IDE будет знать, какие поля у этих объектов есть, и сможет подсказать поле через автодополнение. Дополнительно, в классах можно прикрутить валидацию значений (через тот же pydantic), и, например, если с клиента передаются некорректные данные, сервер сможет это проконтролировать, и вернуть на клиент ошибку с конкретным описанием проблемы.

Пример на [`pydantic`](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic/) (Python 3.6+, `pip install pydantic`):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str
    full_name: str


class Message(BaseModel):
    from_user: User


genMessage = {
    'from_user': {
        'id': 1,
        'username': 'johndoe',
        'full_name': 'John Doe'
    }
}


message = Message.parse_obj(genMessage)

print(message.from_user.id)
```

Пример на [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) ("из коробки" в Python 3.7+ или установить через `pip install dataclasses` на Python 3.6) + [`dacite`](https://pypi.org/project/dacite/) (`pip install dacite`):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dacite import from_dict


@dataclass
class User:
    id: int
    username: str
    full_name: str


@dataclass
class Message:
    from_user: User


genMessage = {
    'from_user': {
        'id': 1,
        'username': 'johndoe',
        'full_name': 'John Doe'
    }
}


message = from_dict(data_class=Message, data=genMessage)

print(message.from_user.id)
```

Comment: в классе `Message(BaseModel)`, почему там `from_user: User`?

Comment: Чтобы вложенный словарь из ключа 'from_user' превратился в объект класса User, и к его полям можно было обращаться через точку.

Comment: У меня с этим кодом, ошибка `id = message.message_id
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'message_id'` и словарь ( новый ) выглядит таким образом:  `from_user=User(id=639141904, username='MaximChyorny', full_name='')`, как я понял ошибка произошла из-за того, что словарь не такой какой нужен для aiogram'a.

Comment: @MaximChyorny в ошибке буквально написано, что у класса Message нет поля message_id, ну вот и добавьте в класс Message поле `message_id: int`, делов-то

Comment: или `message_id: Optional[int]`, если значение может быть не заполнено, не забудьте только добавить импорт `from typing import Optional`

Comment: Разобрался, теперь всё работает

Answer (score 8):

Накидал пример класса-обертки:

- Суть в магическом методе `__getattr__`, который вызывается при запросе поля-атрибута у объекта
- Например, при `x.from_user` в `__getattr__` будет передана строка `from_user`
- Чтобы можно было продолжать цепочку вызова понадобится возвращать объект `WrapperMap` с новым значением

Пример:

```
class WrapperMap:
    def __init__(self, d: dict):
        self.d = d

    def get_value(self):
        return self.d

    def __getattr__(self, item: str) -> 'WrapperMap':
        return self.__class__(self.d.get(item))

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.d)


genMessage = {
    'from_user': {
        'id': 123,
        'username': "username",
        'full_name': "fullName"
    }
}
x = WrapperMap(genMessage)
print(x.from_user.id, type(x.from_user.id))
# 123 <class '__main__.WrapperMap'>

print(x.from_user.username.get_value())
# username
```

Можно немного дописать `__getattr__`, чтобы возвращать обертку только для словарей:

```
    def __getattr__(self, item: str):
        value = self.d.get(item)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            return self.__class__(value)
        
        return value
```

Тогда для получения значений остальных типов не придется вызывать метод `get_value`:

```
x = WrapperMap(genMessage)

print(x.from_user, type(x.from_user))
# {'id': 123, 'username': 'username', 'full_name': 'fullName'} <class '__main__.WrapperMap'>

print(x.from_user.id, type(x.from_user.id))
# 123 <class 'int'>

print(x.from_user.username, type(x.from_user.username))
# username <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Крутое использование рефлексии, чтобы сделать python более javaScript'овым) Правда, будет кошмар, если молодой python'ист начнёт для всех dict'ов писать такие обёртки.

Comment: @SergeyK., спасибо :) Ага, согласен. Лучше использовать вариант через `pydantic` :)